# Multiple observables working together

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, observable

I have an input that as the user types it performs a real-time search. For example, let's say he has searched for the following:

> car

The result would be:

```
[
  {
    id: "1"
    name: "Ferrari"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
    name: "Porsche"
  }
]
```

This I was able to do successfully, here is how:

```
class WordComponent {
  word: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  result: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.subscribe();
  }

  subscribe(): void {
    this.word.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap((word: string): Observable<any[]> => this.http.get(word))
      .subscribe((result: any[]): any[] => this.result = result);
  }

  search(event: any): void {
    this.word.next(event.target.value);
  }

}
```

And the view:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Word" (keyup)="search($event)">
```

I want the user to be able to type multiple words at the same time and perform a real-time search for each word separately. For example, let's say he has searched for the following:

> car food sun

The result for **car** would be:

```
[
  {
    id: "1"
    name: "Ferrari"
  },
  {
    id: "2"
    name: "Porsche"
  }
]
```

The result for **food** would be:

```
[
  {
    id: "3"
    name: "egg"
  },
  {
    id: "4"
    name: "cheese"
  }
]
```

The result for **sun** would be:

```
[
  {
    id: "5"
    name: "star"
  },
  {
    id: "6"
    name: "sky"
  }
]
```

And also merge the results of each word, in this case it would look like this:

```
[
  [{
      id: "1"
      name: "Ferrari"
    },
    {
      id: "2"
      name: "Porsche"
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: "3"
      name: "egg"
    },
    {
      id: "4"
      name: "cheese"
    }
  ],
  [{
      id: "5"
      name: "star"
    },
    {
      id: "6"
      name: "sky"
    }
  ]
]
```

But let's say that the user, after typing all the words and performing the search, wishes to change one of them. Only the search for the word that was changed needs to be redone, and the merge of the final result would also have to be redone.

I still do not know all the features of rxjs and I do not know what would be the ideal way to achieve this. If you want a reference, the [Display Purposes](https://displaypurposes.com/) site has a very similar search engine.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting problem, but I'm not sure this can be solved by using only rxjs operators... There's a really complex logic of extracting the individual words of the stream and finding out which ones have changed. I'd like to know how this gets solved

Comment: I agree that this is a nice question and I'll try to come up with an answer as soon as I get some time for me ;)

Comment: I think Robin Dijkhof's answer is a good start...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
subscribe(): void {
  this.word.debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((words: string): Observable<any[]> => 
    Observable.forkJoin(words.split(' ').map(word => this.http.get(word))) 
  )
  .map(arrayWithArrays => [].concat(arrayWithArrays)
  .subscribe((result: any[]): any[] => this.result = result);
 }
```

Comment: That way you're redoing the calls of words that have not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this huge but partial solution:

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mtawrhLs/1/

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.combineAllCont = function () {
    let lastValues = [];

    return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
        let i = 0;

        let subscription = this.subscribe(stream => {
            const streamIndex = i;
            subscription.add(stream.subscribe(res => {
                lastValues[streamIndex] = res;
                obs.next(lastValues);
            }));
            i++;
        });

        return subscription;
    });
}

/** STUFF TO DEMO **/
let searchBox = [
    '',
    'car',
    'car ',
    'car food',
    'car food sun',
    'cat food sun',
    'cat sun'
]

function performSearch(word) {
    return Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
        console.log('sending search for ' + word);
        return Rx.Observable.of({
            word: word,
            results: word.split('')
        });
    })
}

let searchBoxStream = Rx.Observable.interval(500)
    .take(searchBox.length * 2)
    .map((i) => searchBox[i % searchBox.length]);

/** GOOD STUFF STARTS HERE **/
let wordsStream = searchBoxStream
    .map((str) => str.trim().split(' ').filter((w) => w.trim() != ''));

let wordSearchSubjects = [];
let wordSearchStreamSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);

wordsStream.subscribe((words) => {
    const nWords = words.length;
    const nSubjects = wordSearchSubjects.length;
    // Update streams
    for (i = 0; i < nWords && i < nSubjects; i++) {
        wordSearchSubjects[i].next(words[i]);
    }

    // Create streams
    for (i = nSubjects; i < nWords; i++) {
        const wordSearchSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
        wordSearchSubjects.push(wordSearchSubject);
        wordSearchStreamSubject.next(
            wordSearchSubject.asObservable()
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .flatMap((w) => performSearch(w))
                .concat(Rx.Observable.of(false)) // Ending signal
        )
        wordSearchSubjects[i].next(words[i]);
    }

    // Delete streams
    for (i = nWords; i < nSubjects; i++) {
        wordSearchSubjects[i].complete();
    }
    wordSearchSubjects.length = nWords;
});

let wordSearchStream = wordSearchStreamSubject
    .combineAllCont()
    .map((arr) => arr.filter((r) => r !== false));

resultingStream = wordSearchStream
    .map((arr) => {
        let ret = [];
        arr.forEach(search => {
            ret.push(search.results);
        });
        return ret;
    })
    .subscribe((arr) => console.log(arr));
```

Things to improve:

1. I had to use a custom `combineAll` implementation that doesn't wait the original stream to complete. This can provide memory leaks if it's not correctly implemented, and it should remove the inner subscriptions that complete (it doesn't now)
2. Word change detection has to be improved: Removing a word by the middle makes half of the words to be searched again.

Probably theres a better, more straight-forward solution, but I just could come up with this mess. Feels very hacky/dangerous.

Comment: Wow, you come very close. I'll play around with this jsfiddle and see if I can make any progress. But I also have the same feeling as you, it should have a cleaner way using rxjs operators...

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is very clear. First, we have to perform a diff algorithm on the words. Stale words need to be removed, only new words will be requested.

The only real problem is how we implement it in the cleanest way without any data race. So i come up with one implementation:

```js
searchTags$.pipe(
  scan((pair, tags) => [pair[1] || pair[0], tags], [[]]),
  concatMap(([prevTags, nextTags]) =>
    from(createActions(prevTags, nextTags))
  ),
  reduce((collection$, action) => collection$.pipe(action), of([]))),
  switchMap(stream => stream)
).subscribe(collection => { /*...*/ })

function createActions(prevTags, nextTags) {
  nextTags.reduce((actions, tag) => {
    if (isOld(prevTags, tag)) {
      actions.push(removeAction(tag));
    }
    if (isNew(prevTags, tag)) {
      actions.push(addAction(tag));
    }
    return actions;
  }, []);
}

function removeAction(tag) {
  return map(collection => { collection[tag] = undefined; return collection; });
}

function addAction(tag) {
  return switchMap(collection => requestTag(tag).pipe(map(
    res => { collection[tag] = res; return collection; }
  )));
}
```

That's the shortest that i can do!

Answer (score 0):

5 years later I think I've found another solution which is much simpler, no subscriptions, no subjects, only combining observables. It uses the `switchScan` operator:

```
const words$ = search$.pipe(
  debounceTime(100),
  map((str) =>
    str
      .trim()
      .split(" ")
      .filter((w) => w.trim() !== "")
  )
);

const result$ = words$.pipe(
  switchScan((acc, words) =>
    combineLatest(
      Object.fromEntries(
        words.map((word) => [
          word,
          acc[word]
            ? of(acc[word])
            : fetchWord(word).pipe(startWith(null))
        ])
      )
    ),
    {}
  ),
  map((record) => Object.values(record).filter((v) => v !== null))
);
```

where `search$` is the observable of the input. The `switchScan` every time that there's a new list of words it will create a new observable for each one of them.

But on each one, if it already had a result from a previous emission then it won't do the refetch. If it's a new word instead, then it will do the fetch.

This would also work even when reordering words within the input.